# Facebook Messenger Bot - Share Button

Tags: python, facebook, bots, facebook-messenger

I am trying to develop a Facebook Messenger Bot. I know that for now the bot cannot be added in a group conversation, but there is the share button that share a message with a friend.

The message is sent by the user and not by the bot, therefore the bot doesn't know who received the message.

Do you know if there is a way to trigger the sharing event and save the id of the friend who received the message?

Comment: Are you trying to get an answer for the new solution you came up with because your old solution to the actual problem didn't work out, or are you asking a question for your original question? Because this sounds like a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and not a question regarding your first problem. It is possible to write a "bot" that can write direct messages to people, I've done it and so has a thousand others before me.

Comment: Sorry maybe I wasn't clear. My scenario is that an user is already chatting with my bot, but then he or she wants to include another friend in the conversation. I know that the bot cannot be added in a group, but there is the share button to share a specific message. The problem is that the bot doesn't receive anything when an user share a message, therefore the bot doesn't know who received the message. My question was if there is a way to retrieve the id of the user who received the shared message.

Comment: Looks like Uber is doing it. See end of article. http://www.business2community.com/facebook/nail-referrals-facebook-01681708

Comment: hmm, i don't see any "share message" button in my chat

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for now, there is **no mechanism** announced by Facebook to retrieve the id of a user with whom another user shared a message with. So no, **what you are asking isn't possible**.

All the available methods and ways to work with Facebook Messenger Bots are included inside the [official documentation of the Messenger Platform](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform). If something isn't there, then it's not possible. (At least for now)